# Changing string value with int value in C

Tags: c

I have this issue.

```
    printf("Welcome to The Daily Bugle\n");
    printf("------------Daily Press------------\n");
    printf("Title of the 1. news:");
    read_news_title("news\\1.txt");
    printf("Title of the 2. news:");
    read_news_title("news\\2.txt");
    printf("Title of the 3. news:");
    read_news_title("news\\3.txt");
    printf("Title of the 4. news:");
    read_news_title("news\\4.txt");
```

and read_news_title is here

```
void read_news_title(char* file_path){
    FILE *fp=fopen(file_path,"r");
    char line_buffer[100];
    fscanf(fp,"%[^\n]",line_buffer);
    printf("%s\n",line_buffer);
}
```

I want to convert this like

```
for (int i=1; i<5; i++){
   printf("Title of the new %d",i);
   read_news_title("news\\[i].txt);
   }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: We love that you're here with us and exactly what have you tried and exactly why do you need to rewrite it?

Comment: Use sprintf to build the argument for `read_news_title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes Thanks to the comment section, sprintf is working for this.

I used like this

```
for (int i=1; i<=4; i++){
printf("Title of the %d. news:",i);
sprintf(ch,"\"news\\%d.text\"",i);
printf("%s\n",ch );
}
```

works like a charm!